# jQuery select - cannot get option text or value

Tags: jquery, json, select, dynamic

Using jquery 1.7.1, I'm using json to populate the  dropdown. The code works just great and is is stored in a function but called upon `document.ready()`. I hope someone finds it useful, BUT:

```
proxy.invoke("fetchCHAA", {},
        function(result) {

            if (result == null) {
                alert("Possible error in fetching list of CHAAs");
                return;
            }
            else {

                var optionsValues = '<select>';
                optionsValues += '<option value=""></option>';
                $.each(result, function() {
                    optionsValues += '<option value="' + this.chaa_id + '">' + this.chaa_name + '</option>';
                });
                optionsValues += '</select>';
                var options = $('#optionsChaa');

                options.replaceWith(optionsValues);


            }


        }, onPageError);
```

As I said, the problem lies with .change event or even attempting to get the value of the selected item. For example, we know that

```
var id = $("#optionsChaa").val();
// should bring back the chaa_id
```

Or:

```
var text = $("#optionsChaa").text();
// should bring back the chaa name
```

The problem is that bringing back the ID or TEXT through `.val()` is always undefined. I've noticed that others seem to have the same problem yet seemingly unable to address it.

I even added the change event to the optionsValue object hoping that it will work after the DOM is loaded but that does not seem to work as well.

I don't want to hard code the list of options on the page but it looks like I might have to.

Comment: Aren't you erasing the select's ID with your replaceWith call, meaning jQuery can no longer find it with that selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `var optionsValues = '<select>';` to var `optionsValues = '<select id="optionsChaa">';`

The ID is getting lost I think.

**edit**  @David M beat me to it, that's the answer.

Comment: David M and Jonathan. Here's a baseball bat for each one of you. Go gentle, okay? :-) Thanks!

Comment: Ha, I don't want to fight, can I gift some rep?

Comment: The code works great - dyanmically loading the select drop down but the kicker is when using .change the result is undefined....